# why does wmi process win32_xxx queries faster than cim_xxx queries?

Tags: wmi

PS D:\work\scripts> measure-command { get-wmiobject -query "select * from win32_service" | Where-Object -FilterScript {$
_.Name -eq "WinRM"} }

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 426
Ticks             : 4262955
TotalDays         : 4.93397569444444E-06
TotalHours        : 0.000118415416666667
TotalMinutes      : 0.007104925
TotalSeconds      : 0.4262955
TotalMilliseconds : 426.2955

PS D:\work\scripts> measure-command { get-wmiobject -query "select * from cim_service" | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.
Name -eq "WinRM"} }

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 1
Seconds           : 35
Milliseconds      : 320
Ticks             : 953208058
TotalDays         : 0.00110325006712963
TotalHours        : 0.0264780016111111
TotalMinutes      : 1.58868009666667
TotalSeconds      : 95.3208058
TotalMilliseconds : 95320.8058

Comment: What is the point in comparing queries that retrieve different data subsets?

Answer (score 0):

it is simple - by querying CIM_Service you retrieve more information (as CIM services are not limited by Win32 services; moreover win32_service instances are contained within CIM_Service). 
That is - your queries differ significantly in the amount of data retrieved.

You can easily explore it via WMI CIM Studio.